# How to write content inside all div under a parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I am planning to write pagination manually for a slider. Now this pagination is printing like this

```
<div class="tp-bullets  simplebullets custom">
    <div class="bullet first"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet selected"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet last"></div>
    <div class="tpclear"></div>
</div>
```

now its printing empty pagination. I want to write `<span>content</span>` in all div under the div having c`lass-name=tp-bullets  simplebullets custom` using `javascript`  someone please help me to do this. I am very basic about js.

Comment: Do do you mean that you want to add `<span>content</span>` to all the `<div>` that are inside of `<div class="tp-bullets  simplebullets custom">`?

Comment: hello! can you format source code, and also give example of html what you want to achieve?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek ya you got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do:

```
$(".tp-bullets").children("div").html("<span>content</span>");
```

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/keq8qnfr/)**

If you want to add different items you can do something like this:

```
var myItems = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8"];

$(".tp-bullets").children("div").each(function( index ) {
    $(this).html("<span>"+myItems[index]+"</span>");
});
```

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/keq8qnfr/1/)**

Comment: suppose if i want different content in each div ?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.tp-bullets > div').append('<span>content</span>')
```

Comment: suppose if i want different content in each div ?

Comment: What content do you want in each div? Is there a pattern? Try using .each()

Answer (score 0):

here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/66/
I dont think you intended `<div class="tpclear"></div>` to have `<span>Content</span>` since it seemed like a clearing bullet versus a content bullet, so i used class `.bullet` instead to set up the content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        $('.bullet').html('<span>Content</span>');
    });
});
```

hope this helps!

EDIT: if you want different text for each div you can use this: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/67/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divArray = [
        'Bullet 1 Content',
        'Bullet 2 Content',
        'Bullet 3 Content',
        'Bullet 4 Content',
        'Bullet 5 Content',
        'Bullet 6 Content',
        'Bullet 7 Content',
    ]
    $('.add').on('click', function() {
        var count = 0;
        $('.bullet').each(function () {
            $(this).html('<span>' + divArray[count] + '<span>');
            count++;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascript

```
var div = document.getElementById('divID');

div.innerHTML = '<span>content</span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[JQuery .find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**, **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** and **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** methods:

```
var divs = $( "div" );
var contents=["content1", "content2", "content3", "content4", "content5", "content6", "content7", "content8"];
$('.tp-bullets').find(divs).each(function() {
    $(this).append('<span>'+contents[i]+'</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Javascript

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.tp-bullets.simplebullets.custom')).forEach(function(el){
    el.innerHTML = '<span>Content</span>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one more clear js with jsfiddle

```
<div class="tp-bullets  simplebullets custom">
    <div class="bullet first"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet selected"></div>
    <div class="bullet"></div>
    <div class="bullet last"></div>
    <div class="tpclear"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".bullet");

for(var i = 0; i< x.length; i++){
    x[i].innerHTML = "red";
}}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eL852m86/1/